# creating rubygem from assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sass, coffeescript

I have a few coffeescript and sass files. I want to create a rubygem so I can easily use these files in every project.
How can I do this? Where I must put these files in my gem folder?

Comment: Check this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines

Comment: http://integrumtech.com/2010/01/how-to-build-a-ruby-gem/

Comment: thx for link, but I want release it as a gem. where I must put static files like these assets? in lib directory?

Comment: The rails mountable engine generator prepares everything for you even the gemspec. I use this for 3 of our projects sharing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the [assets pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline)? If you place the assets inside your lib/assets directory then rails will make them automatically loaded for you. All you need to do is require them in the application.js or application.cs `//= require name_of_your_asset`. Check how [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) has [solved](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/tree/master/vendor/assets) it